# Feeding 2 subpanels from one main

Tags: subpanel

I have 2 different electrical projects going on: running electric to a detached garage and running electric to a shed. I would like to put a subpanel for each. The garage I would like 200amps and the shed 50amps. Both will be fed from my main residential box. I understand that I need #2AWG for my 200amp and #6AWG for my 50amp.
I already have an empty 2" PVC40 conduit buried and going to the garage.
I was thinking of using a 2" Type "T" conduit body to tee off of the 2" PVC and use a 1" adapter to run to the shed.
My concern is running the #2AWG and #6AWG in the same 2" pipe.
Will it work? Is it advisable?

Thanks,
Armando

Comment: Is your main panel big enough?  Are you planning to use all that power or is that just the size of the sub panels?  Sub panels can be fed by smaller breakers.

Comment: How many square feet are the garage and the shed respectively, and what loads are you wanting to support at each building?

Comment: If you meant #2 for **100** amp, then exact wire size and type should to be calculated, but generally if load calcs are satisfied the concept would be OK. (My rough fill calculation based even on worst case minimum 90°C larger aluminum wire size for each feeder derated 80%

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different unasked issues here, such as:

- Load Calculation - you need to make sure that each panel is sized greater than or equal to the planned loads (it is not quite as simple as "add the amps"), and just as important that the main panel, *and the utility service*, can handle all the new loads in addition to existing loads.
- Wire type and size - hopefully you are planning on aluminum, because while it typically needs to be one size larger than copper, it is usually *much* less expensive than copper at large sizes. 6 AWG aluminum can handle 50A. 2 AWG copper will get you 115 amp and 2 AWG aluminum will only get you 100 amp - but neither comes close to 200 amp. However, if you are putting in a 200A rated panel (which is fine, and it can have a bundled 200A main breaker as a shutoff/disconnect switch) but actually feeding it from the main panel using a 90A breaker, *and your load calculation only requires 90A*, then 2 AWG aluminum is fine. (To be honest, if you don't go crazy on EV charging and don't put in a tankless hot water heater, 90A should be more than adequate for a garage.)

Back to the original question: conduit size. The easy way to figure it out is a conduit fill calculator such as [this one from Southwire](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-conduit):

I put in 4 x 2 AWG aluminum and 3 x 6 AWG aluminum and get just over 17% fill. Your actual fill may be less - I am pretty sure the ground (I only put in 1, they can share) can be smaller.

You should check (unless you already have) the rules for where you need Schedule 80 instead of Schedule 40, but even with Schedule 80 (thicker pipe so less room inside) you are under 20%.

Answer (score 1):

### Wire sizes...

> I understand that I need #2AWG for my 200amp and #6AWG for my 50amp

You're going to need a fresher copy of Table 310.15(B)(16). Yours has a smudge on it.  **For 200A, you'll need 250 kcmil wire** (205A wire).  #2 wire is only good for 90A.

I assume we're talking aluminum here; using copper at these large feeder sizes is just ill-informed. (but we do get a lot of novices thinking that, because of some trouble that happened with *small branch circuit* wiring in the 70s.  Which has been fully resolved by the way, and never affected large feeder.)  #2 copper is still only 115A.

### Adjusting for multiple circuits

> My concern is running the #2AWG and #6AWG in the same 2" pipe. Will it work? Is it advisable?

Well first, 250 kcmil won't fit in a 2" pipe with anything else.

But regardless, with two circuits in the pipe, you need to derate to 80% of wire ampacity *at the wire thermal limits* (important point here).  You are limited to 75°C thermal numbers due to the thermal ratings of the terminals in residential panels.  However the terminal *is not inside the conduit*, so you get to use the wire rating of, I presume 90 degrees C.

- The 60A wire must be 75A *at its thermal limit of 90°C* which happily is the case for #6 copper and #4 aluminum.
- The 200A wire must be 250A *at 90°C* and that requires 300 kcmil aluminum or 4/0 copper.

### Conduit fill precludes aluminum... ouch!

However the only way to shimmy all 8 wires into a 2" conduit is to *both* use all-copper (price OUCH!!!!) and also use **bare** ground wires (the insulation puts you over fill).

Of course if you had no idea aluminum was even viable, you're coming into this already expecting to pay for copper, so I suppose it won't be the sticker shock it would otherwise be.

### Instead, rethink.

First, on aluminum wire. The lugs you're attaching to in the subpanels are *made of aluminum*. Thermal expansion differences work favorably when aluminum *is the lug*.  And obviously Al wire on Al lug works fine. At 1/3 the cost, I recommend aluminum wire and then spend the savings *actually* improving safety. #1 torque driver to torque screws to spec. #2 proper 4-wire feeders and ground rods. #3 GFCIs, AFCIs and whatnot.  #4 excessively large subpanels so you never run out of spaces (or do stupid crud because you ran out of spaces).

The second thing I'd rethink is - well, I don't know your site layout but if both feeders are in the same conduit, surely the shed line is coming *via* the garage, so why not feed the shed subpanel **from** the garage subpanel?  Like I say it depends on wire routing, but this way you'd only have one feeder in the 2" pipe.  The *derate* goes away. You can use 250 kcmil aluminum. Everyone wins.

Third, I'd rethink 200A in a garage. Honestly when I heard 200A I thought "that sounds like a random 'picked out of the air' number we get all the time from novices who don't really understand the material".

You haven't discussed your loads and I'm fine with that.  It's fine to run a 200A feeder to a garage off even a 200A panel - the feeder size doesn't matter, what matters is the loads you actually put on it.  In that, you will have *practical limits* due to NEC Article 220's Load Calculations, of which you have three:

- for the shed subpanel's loads
- for the garage's loads (inclusive of shed if you daisy-chain them)
- for all loads on the meter/service.

The loads already in the house can't be made to "go away"*.  Allocation must be made for them.  "I promise not to use dryer/range/WH/heat pump while running the tankless in the garage" doesn't work.  **So you have practical limits to the sizes of the loads that could be supported at garage and shed**.  If you are unlikely to be able to use more than 90A or 120A out there (common inexpensive feeder sizes that will amply fit in your pipe), then running 200A feeder out there is just dumb.

"who cares, the cost is tiny" well you should care when cost is *not* tiny because of being forced into copper wire due to conduit fill limits.

Every dollar you spend on copper is a dollar you can't spend on *actual* safety stuff that matters. (which may not even be electrical).

* Now, they do make Load Shed devices which will suspend certain loads to avoid panel overload. For EV charging, the tech is amazing - it can actually *slow down* the EV charge instead of shutting it off entirely.) But still, all this needs to be accounted for.